# How to customize a character with new objects (clothes, body parts) in a 3D game?

Tags: unity, 3d, character

how do we customize a character in a game by adding, for example, a different clothing? The character has an armature, made in Blender, if I add a new object with the game engine, I would have to copy the position for each frame, and the orientation?
Or is there a technique to make the model in Blender with different meshes, find the meshes in the .dae file (for scenekit, but it might be the same for fbx for unity), and replace it with a new object, and the orientation will be automatically copied?

Has anyone had some experience with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parent the objects to bones and they will move with the bones.

Answer (score 5):

this problem is divided into two situations：

#### first: sword,

this thing can be just parented to the bone, then it will move with bone;

#### second: cloth,

in blender, you need to use the same armature, then create two different cloth, and rig the cloth mesh to the armature.

in unity3d, read this article:

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/stitch-multiple-body-parts-into-one-character.16485/